# Proof of infinitude of the number of primes of the form $4k+1$

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, prime-numbers

Would this work?

If the number of primes of a given form is finite, then the number $$M = (4k_1 + 1)(4k_2 + 1) \ldots (4k_n + 1) + 4$$ should be composite. But the product of numbers of the form $4k + 1$ also gives $4k + 1$, so $M = 4K + 1 + 4 = 4(K + 1) + 1$, and $M$ is prime because it leaves a remainder of $4$ after dividing by any prime of the given form; also $M$ is not divisible by $4$. So that should be contradiction.

Comment: Why should you assume that ".. then the number
$M = ...$ should be composite" from its structure? Also note that your process of proof by contradiction is wrong, since there are primes of the form $4k+3$ as well, apart from primes of the form $4k+1$.

Comment: You should actually *state* that $4k_i + 1$ actually are the primes of that form and they are all of them.  As it is I have utterly no reason to assume $(4*1+1)(4*1+1) + 4$ is composite if there are only $157$ primes of the form $4m + 1$.

Comment: "and M is prime because it leaves reminder 4 after dividing with any prime of given form"  So?  Maybe all its prime factors of the form $4k + 3$?

Comment: Yes I get that argument is wrong thanks to answers posted $40$ mins ago

Comment: With $n=2,k_1=1,k_2=3,$ we have $M=(5)(13)+4=69=(3)(23).$ The error is assuming that $M$ cannot be a product of an even number of primes, each $1$ less than a multiple of $4$. It is never a bad idea to test a general statement with some small or simple examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All right, the argument doesn't work as it stands. But then, can we fix it? Do we have a way to construct numbers that definitely aren't divisible by any primes congruent to $3$ mod $4$?

The trick:

> A sum of squares $a^2+b^2$ is divisible by a prime $p$ congruent to $3$ mod $4$ only if both $a$ and $b$ are divisible by $p$. So, then, we just need to replace that product of primes with a perfect square that fills the same role.

Also, as noted in the comment, you're skipping steps in the logic. What exactly are those $4k_i+1$? Why should the number you construct be composite? An experienced mathematician will likely know how these gaps should be filled, but you can't always assume that your audience will, or that the audience will give you the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: The hint you gave....why is that so?

Comment: It boils down to "$-1$ isn't a square mod $p$". Lots of ways to prove that, but I'll go with saying that the product of everything nonzero is $-1$, and since half of them are non-squares, that product isn't a square.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not correct. You cannot deduce that $M$ is prime. Note that $M$ could be the product of an even number of primes of the form $4k-1$.

Comment: Oh that's right, it could be divisible by some prime of different form

Answer (score 2):

You can make it work with a little adjustment.

Let $q$ be the largest prime of the form $q=4k+1$. Then let

$$x = 2\prod_{p \in \mathbb{P}; \ p \le q} p,$$

where here $\mathbb{P}$ denotes the set of *odd* primes. and let us set $M = x^2+1$. Now let $q'$ be a prime that divides $M$. Then as $M$ is odd, it follows that $q'$ must be odd, and as $q$ and no odd prime smaller than $q$ divides $M$ it follows that $q' > q$. Now if $q'$ is $M$ itself then we are done [why].  We note the following otherwise:

$$M - 1 = x^2 \equiv -1 \mod q'$$

This implies that

> $x^4 \equiv 1$ mod $q'$ and so (as $x^2 \not \equiv 1$ mod $q'$) that the order of $x$ in $\left(\mathbb{F}_{q'}\right)^{\times}$ is precisely 4, which implies that $|\left(\mathbb{F}_{q'}\right)^{\times}| = q'-1$ is divisible by 4.

Can you finish the rest?